# How to keep div on bottom of screen after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a contact button that is located within the visible part of the screen between 2 content items. Once the user scrolls down I want the button fixed at the botton of the screen so it will always be within sight.

```js
var pos = $('#test').scrollTop();
if (pos > 200) $('#test').addclass('fixed')
console.log(pos)
```

```css
.fixed {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#test {
  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#content2 {
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="test">button</div>
<div id="content2"></div>
```

The problem is to know when the button will be out of sight in order to append the fixed function.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `.offsetTop`. So add this and it will use your class `fixed` to do what you need.

```
var fixButton = document.getElementById("test");
var sticky = fixButton.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    fixButton.classList.add("fixed");
  } else {
    fixButton.classList.remove("fixed");
  }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/07t3x4nk/)

Answer (score 1):

Bro Do you want this.. ! Check it out I have fixed it

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 190) {
        $("#test").addClass("fixed-btn");
    }
    if (scroll <= 190) {
        $("#test").removeClass("fixed-btn");
    }
});
```

```css
.fixed {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#test {
  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#content2 {
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}
.fixed-btn {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    }
    body {
    margin: 0;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="test">button</div>
<div id="content2"></div>
```

Comment: Almost! The 200 is just an example, I want the footer to apear at the bottom as soon as the button is out of sight. So one would need to know when it disapears from view.

Comment: Bro let me make it more smooth

Comment: This solution implies why your code wasn't working, you want the page's scroll position, since the #test element itself doesn't generate a scrolling region.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on user scroll for example via the jQuery scroll function on the window element. Save the offset and height of the object on document.ready and when both values added are <= the pageY Offset of the window they are out of sight.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const btnOffsetTop = $('#test')[0].offsetTop;
  const btnHeight = $('#test')[0].scrollHeight;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
   if(btnOffsetTop + btnHeight 
    <= window.pageYOffset){
  $('#test').addClass('fixed');
   }else{
    $('#test').removeClass('fixed');
   }
  });
});
```

```css
.fixed {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#test {
  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#content2 {
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="test">button</div>
<div id="content2"></div>
```